# Show/Hide div based on list count

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to show/hide a div based on the list count (the list is on the code behind) "async". I mean, I want it to show when the list has more then 0 items and hide when it has none. Presently I have this:

```
<div class="col-xs-3" style="padding:0; margin:0 0 0 1%;">
        <div class="@((Repository.Reservation.BookedRooms.Count>0)?"visible":"hidden")">

            <div style="background-color:red; width:20px; height:20px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But this only applies on page rendering. Is there a way to do this without having to resort to javascript, with CSS/bootstrap only?

I could do it on the javascript button click events I have to add/remove an item, but it would be simpler if I could do it with just CSS/bootstrap (I mean, if it's simpler, of course).

Comment: How's so? I don't have any ul elements. I tried adding a ul element and implementing that in a style attribute but it doesn't do anything. Like <ul style="ul:empty ~ div > div {display:none;}"></ul>

Comment: I honestly can't quite understand it. Could you show me an example where it would work? The thing is, the list I want to evaluate is in the code behind and I want the div to evaluate if it's empty or not always. For instance, if I clicked on a button I could do it on the click event. I want to do the same with CSS. But it only evaluates the expressions given on page load. It probably isn't viable.

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect that to work. Does nothing change on the client side (the generated webpage in the browser) while the server is working? Then how is the browser to know that there are changes at all? There has to be _some_ communication between the browser and the server. Conclusion: JavaScript.

Comment: Since you marked this with an asp.net core-2.0 tag ...you could use the following in your cshtml page with Razor...                                                                                                  
 <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding:0; margin:0 0 0 1%;">
    @if (Repository.Reservation.BookedRooms.Count > 0)
    {
        <div style="background-color:red; width:20px; height:20px;"></div>
    }
</div>

Comment: @MrLister, I know about javascript. I was just looking for a simpler CSS/bootstrap/razor way to do this. But I guess it's only possible with javascript. Thanks, anyway. :)

Comment: @LesP, thanks. I tried it but that only works on page load. After that, it will not be changed again, even if the count changes on the code behind.

Comment: @MrLister, Oh, and the count of the list I'm checking changes (by adding/removing elements) when a button is clicked. The thing is, I'm trying to do this not only for the div to appear or not. That was just an example of one of the things I want to do. Then, I want to have a loop to show all the properties of each object in the list. With razor, that's easy to do. In javascript, I'll have to check. Never done that.

Comment: Does it still exist on core? I'm transitioning from classic asp.net to core and that was one of the first things I tried. But I thought it was gone. How does it work now? Did a quick search now and I can't find anything.

Comment: @taiko Oops, sorry. I should have noticed that.

Comment: That's all right. Could still exist and I not know about it. I'd actually prefer it, since I don't know what (if anything) can be used now to simulate that effect.